# Как избавиться от длинного switch case в шаблоне

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular, angular4, angular5

Есть `<div>` который должен содержать форму ввода, но для разных случаев есть много разных форм компонентов

```
<app-support-error>
<app-support-billing>
<app-support-info>
...
```

Их довольно много в будущем обещают разростаться все перечислять смысла нет.
Для определения какую из них показывать у объекта темы поддержки приходящей с бэка есть тип, и соответсвующий этим типам `enum`.
Как мне произвести передачу в мой основной компонент, компонента с соответстующей формы, но только без длинного списка `*ngIf` типо

```
<app-support-error *ngIf="typeAsError">
<app-support-billing *ngIf="typeAsBilling">
<app-support-info *ngIf="typeAsInfo">
// И так далее...
```

Или `switchCase` без разницы одинаково плохо

Хотелось бы использовать что-то вроде шаблона команд, тоесть иметь массив из этих компонентов на TS стороне родителя, и найдя нужный по условию в цикле отрисовать его в нужном месте родителя. Может разновидностей форм потом сто разных будет, и файл станет просто бесконечным.

Но тут есть 2 проблемы:

1. Как присвоить переменной инстанс компонента `const err = new SupportErrorComponent();` Так по всей видимости не выйдет. И тут совсем не понятно как поступить.
2. Поместить нужный компонент в определенное место родителя (тут напрашивается `ng-content`)

Возможно ли это средствами Angular 7 или я много хочу. Есть возможно то как? Буду признателен как за идеи в любом виде, так и за обоснованные аргументы что это точно не получится. Или как-то еще можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На помощь приходит ручная инициализация компонентов, которая позволяет вынести фактически всю бизнес логику из шаблона в код.

Первый вариант - использование `ComponentFactoryResolver`. Он дает возможность получить скомпилированную фабрику компонента, которая предоставляет интерфейс для инициализации компонента. Вы привели в пример такой шаблон:

```
<app-support-error>
<app-support-billing>
<app-support-info>
```

У вас под рукой есть конструкторы этих компонентов, для `app-support-error` - предполагаю `SupportErrorComponent` и так далее. Все компоненты нужно добавить в `entryComponents` модуля, в скоупе которого вы их объявляете (`declarations`):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [SupportErrorComponent],
  entryComponents: [SupportErrorComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Когда компилятор натыкается на свойство `entryComponents` - он генерирует фабрики до рантайма.

Вы говорите, что у вас есть `enum` с типами того, что возвращает API. Нам в этом случае нужна хеш-таблица (ключ-значение), то есть тип-компонент:

```
type SupportComponent =
  SupportErrorComponent |
  SupportBillingComponent |
  SupportInfoComponent;

const enum SupportType {
  Error,
  Billing,
  Info
}

const supportComponents = {
  // `app-support-error`
  [SupportType.Error]: SupportErrorComponent,
  // `app-support-billing`
  [SupportType.Billing]: SupportBillingComponent,
  // `app-support-info`
  [SupportType.Info]: SupportInfoComponent
};

function getSupportComponent(type: SupportType) {
  return supportComponents[type];
}
```

Дело за малым, нужный конструктор для нужного типа у нас есть. Теперь остается написать функционал для инициализации компонента:

```
function renderSupportComponent(
  type: SupportType,
  resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  injector: Injector
): ComponentRef<SupportComponent> {
  const component = getSupportComponent(type);
  const factory: ComponentFactory<SupportComponent> = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
  // `0` - индекс, куда проецировать шаблон в контейнере (т.е. в самое начало)
  return viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector);
}
```

`renderSupportComponent` - это функция, которая параметром принимает тип, который вам возвращает ваше API (подставьте свой), инстанс `ComponentFactoryResolver`, у которого есть доступ к закешированным фабрикам, инстанс `ViewContainerRef` - абстракция из ядра Angular, представляет из себя контейнер для создания динамических представлений разными способами (используя фабрики либо `TemplateRef`), инстанс `Injector` - чтобы у динамического компонента был также доступ к системе DI.

В шаблоне компонента, где вы проджектите в данный момент эти селекторы:

```
<app-support-error>
<app-support-billing>
<app-support-info>
```

Можете убрать их и заменить на:

```
<ng-container #support></ng-container
```

`ng-container` - это элемент без селектора (его нет в DOM дереве, но есть в памяти). Это будет плейсхолдер для наших динамических компонентов, то есть место, куда мы их будем проджектить, мы можем получить к нему доступ из компонента, используя `@ViewChild`:

```
class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('support', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  public supportContainer: ViewContainerRef = null;
}
```

После того, как вы сделали запрос и вам пришел ответ - можете использовать функцию `renderSupportComponent`:

```
@ViewChild('support', { read: ViewContainerRef })
public supportContainer: ViewContainerRef = null;

private ref: ComponentRef<SupportComponent> | null = null;

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector) {}

public makeSomeRequest(): void {
  this.someService.makeSomeRequest().pipe(
    map((type: SupportType) =>
      renderSupportComponent(type, this.resolver, this.supportContainer, this.injector);
    )
  ).subscribe((ref: ComponentRef<SupportComponent>) => {
    this.ref = ref;
  });
}
```

`ComponentRef` - это ссылка на инициализированный динамеческий компонент, нужно для того, чтоб мы могли освобождать ресурсы. Для того, чтобы уничтожить компонент, достаточно вызвать `destroy`:

```
this.ref.destroy();
this.ref = null;
```

Также можно добавить `ngOnDestroy` хук, чтоб уничтожать компонент вместе с родителем:

```
public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this.ref) {
    this.ref.destroy();
    this.ref = null;
  }
}
```

Еще есть второй вариант - структурная директива. Это в том случае, если вы хотели бы переиспользовать эту логику:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[support]' })
export class SupportDirective implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input('support')
  public type: SupportType = null;

  private ref: ComponentRef<SupportComponent> | null = null;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.dispose();
    this.create(changes.type.currentValue);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dispose();
  }

  private create(type: SupportType): void {
    this.ref = renderSupportComponent(
      type,
      this.resolver,
      this.viewContainerRef,
      this.injector
    );
  }

  private dispose(): void {
    if (this.ref) {
      this.ref.destroy();
      this.ref = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Вам нужно сеттить тип, возвращаемый сервером, в свойство компонента:

```
this.someService.makeSomeRequest().subscribe((type) => {
  this.type = type;
});
```

Шаблон также превращается в:

```
<ng-container *support="type"></ng-container>
```